# How is billing being performed for Active Directory users belonging to multiple Stack Overflow for Teams Business using the same ADFS?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have just presented Stack Overflow for Teams to my manager and he informed that the most probable use case is to have multiple teams based on content. However, some employees might belong to more than one team (e.g. general team, some business unit team).

This kind of defeats the purpose of SO for Teams which aims of building a rather large community inside the company, but this is the hard reality of keeping some things separate.

We were wondering about the financial perspective. How is billing being performed? Is a user billed twice if they belong to two private teams?

**Question:** How is billing being performed for Active Directory users belonging to multiple Stack Overflow for Teams Business using the same ADFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our [Enterprise version](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise) can host sub-teams within the larger Team.

This means that if certain content is specific to only certain groups, they can have their own sub-team and still get the full benefits of being part of the larger Team.

[image]